# Is my divergence test correct?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals, divergent-series

This idea came to me while looking at the following graph of $f=\frac{1}{x}$:
[image]

Now, the definite integral of $f$ from $1$ to $n$ is smaller than $f(1)+f(2)...f(n)$, from the graph above. 
But since the definite integral from $1$ to $n$ is $\log(n)$, which as we take the limit of  $n$ to $\infty$, $\log(n)$ goes to $\infty$ as well. Hence the infinte series $f(1)+f(2)+f(3)...$ goes to $\infty$, that is diverges.

Thinking about this gave me an idea, to extend this to any function $h$, not discontinuous on an infinte number of points, satisfying the following conditions:

- $h(n)\geq h(x) \text{ whenever } n>x>n+1 $
- $h(x) > 0$
- $\lim_{x\to\infty}\int^x_a h(x)\, dx = \infty $

Then, $\sum_{i=a}^{\infty}h(i)$ diverges, where is $a$ and $n$ are natural numbers and $n\geq a$. The problem is I cannot prove it, I have not studied analysis or series. I don't know how to prove it without analysis, using proven theorems.

So, I ask here that is my test correct? I hope so, but there are so weird continuous functions that it doesn't give me any confidence. If you have a not-so-tough proof, it would be very appreciated. If it is so, how can I generalize this or relax the conditions?

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/IntegralTest.aspx

Comment: If you read some material about Riemann integral and think again you will be able to figure it out yourself.

Comment: I'm sure you can figure out an informal "proof" using the additivity property of integrals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is called the [integral test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence), and proofs of it are in almost any calculus book, but are little more than what you've mentioned.

Comment: Wiki gives these conditions: Consider an integer N and a non-negative function f defined on the unbounded interval [N, ∞), on which it is monotone decreasing. If the integral diverges, then the series diverges as well. But my conditions are a bit more general, I think, what is going on?

Comment: And also, the article does not mention $f$ is to be continuous?

Comment: No, only decreasing and $>0$.

Comment: @mookid But if $f$ is discontinuous on non finite no. of points, then the integral would not necessarily exist? [And yes, $f$ may be discontinuous at finite no. of points, I get that].

Comment: @Sawarnik : the integral is in this case not defined by the limit of Riemann sums, but can be defined with the same properties, for example if is piecewise continuous.

Answer (score 1):

You have a stronger theorem, saying that if $f$ is positive and decreasing, then the series $$
\sum \left\{f(n) - \int_n^{n+1}f (t)dt\right\}
$$converges.

Then there is convergence of the original series iff the primitives of $f$ have a finite limit as $x\to\infty$.

Let me write the (simple) proof here:
$$ f(n+1) \le\int_n^{n+1}f(t)dt \le f(n) $$
$$ f(n) - f(n+1)\ge f(n) - \int_n^{n+1}f(t)dt \ge 0 $$
so, as $f$ has a limit when $t\to\infty$, $\sum \{f(n) - f(n+1)\}$  and by comparison principle: $$
\sum \left\{f(n) - \int_n^{n+1}f (t)dt\right\}\le \infty
$$

Comment: Thanks, mookid. Will look over this later.